# Gravitational flatness, the topography of Lagrange "points"

Tags: gravity, orbital-mechanics

Just how gravitationally flat are real Lagrange Points? Many classic "jump drives" require "flat space" in order to fire, the classic diagram of Lagrange Points as shown below suggests ridges or plateaus of flat space with null gravity around the Lagrange Points but it deals with a simple three body system, solar systems are a good deal more complex so how much of that flatness is lost to perturbations from the likes of Jupiter, in other words influences outside the basic three body system of the Sun-Earth-Moon?

Classic three-body system:
[image]

Comment: Normally it's a good idea to wait at least 24 hours before accepting a question so that people from every time zone have a chance to weigh in.

Comment: Sorry normally I leave it for weeks until I get a nudge, unless it's on Sci-fi Fantasy.SE, they encourage a fast turnaround on correct answers.

Comment: actually these ain't points but rather orbits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't flat.

To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point):

> The Lagrange points mark positions where the combined gravitational pull of the two large masses provides precisely the centripetal force required to orbit with them.

There is still a gravitational force (a slope) at a lagrange point so that an object with no velocity would still fall out of position.

Comment: Cool that answers the question, a "Jump Zone" at a Lagrange Point would need to be artificial.

Comment: Although L1 and L2 themselves are not flat, there is a point just outside L1 that is (instantaneously) flat:  Objects there will be "going straight" in solar-centered space, though they'll appear to fall toward Earth as it moves in it's orbit.